# Should we report when mobile application is responding slow on slow network

Tags: manual-testing, performance

I am testing an Android based application. Which is responding slow. Meaning the fetching display late on slow network reception.

Should I report it or not? I'm a beginner tester in this organization.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but related questions: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/16640/should-testers-first-discuss-a-bug-with-the-developers-before-writing-a-bug-repo

Answer (score 1):

Testers should signal issues they think might cause problems in the field. Of-course slow performance is one of these possible issues. Do not [triage issues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_bug#Bug_management) yourself, do it together with the test/development/product team.

If it is a critical issue depends on the product. Now the question should you formally report this in a defect tracker? Maybe, but I would first spar with the person who defines the requirements for this product. Discuss if performance issues like this should be reported. Maybe the product will only be used by people on really fast devices and connections. After the discussion decide to track the issues or added to a list of known trivial issues.

Answer (score 0):

This question is destined to be closed as Not Enough Information, but it has a good generic answer- Why do you ask us ?

Ask the developers, ask the product managers, ask the users- both existing and future imaginary ones (what would you think if you were one ?).

Ask the bug tracking system (or just look on past bugs and how were they handled), ask other testers those who handle functionality and those who test performance, ask your manager and manager's manager, ask the CEO (I did !).

Consult the literature, newspapers, market research papers, academic UI research papers, customer surveys.

Go read the requirements, not just the developers version but also how the product and sales department see them.

And finally use some common sense.

Answer (score 0):

Application running slow generally considered under performance testing related concerns. So this defect is generally should be reported under performance testing cycle. You can check for any performance tester to get more info about this. But as mentioned by others that you have to consult others like developer team, BAs etc in order to clarify that whether this slow running is really a concern for the managers or users of application or not. If the application is intentionally designed such that it runs slow on slow networks then this should not be defect.